# Oracle SQL: Compare all values from 2 columns and exchange them

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, if-statement, cursor

I have a Oracle DB with a table called `myC`. In this table I have a few row, two of them called `myCheight, myCwidth`.

I need to read these values and compare them like in `IF myCheight > myCwidth DO switch the values.`

I tried to read values from one row but didnt get it to work. I use Oracles Oracle SQL Developer.

This is what i came up with so far:

```
set serveroutput on;
DECLARE 
  cursor h is select * from MyC;
  type htype is table of h%rowtype index by number;

  stage_tab htype;
  master_tab htype;
BEGIN 
  open h;
  loop  
      fetch h bulk collect into stage_tab limit 500;

      for i in 1 .. stage_tab.count loop
          master_tab(stage_tab(i).id) := stage_tabe(i);
      end loop;

      exit when h%notfound;
  end loop;
  close h;

end;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Can't you just do this?

```
UPDATE myC
    SET myCheight = myCwidth,
        myCwidth = myCheight
    WHERE myCheight > myCwidth
```

Comment: +1 : Agreed.  `SET myCheight = myCwidth` isn't completed before `myCwidth = myCheight`, they 'appear' to happen at the same time.

Comment: +1. You can also add a sign: *"Don't try this at home (or MySQL)"*